# What is the meaning of "with" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "with" in the following sentence,

> His face was twisted **with** pain

Does "His face was twisted" mean "His face was twisted. And the pain was revealed in his face" ?
Or does it mean "His face was twisted because of pain" ?

I thought that I understood this simple sentence, but now it is ambiguous. I have always interpreted "with" as "because of" in similar sentences.  By the way, suddenly I feel like I have misinterpreted and understood it so far. Have I ever really known something wrong?

Comment: This is an instrumental use of *with,* similar to how you say "I write with a pen."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, there's really no difference between your two definitions.  In this case "with" does mean "because of" -- but the only way an outside observer could know that he was in pain was by looking at the expression on his face.    The man was in pain, and so his face was making a *twisted* (i.e. a *tortured*) expression.

A similar example:

> Her face was shining **with** joy.

Is her face shining because she is joyful?  Or do other people know she is joyful because her face is shining?  It seems to me these are really two sides of the same thing.

Comment: If so, for example, a person is really not sick. But, a person want to prentend to be sick. He is twisted on his face not because he is in pain, but because his face was frowned(twisted) to cheat.
If a person frowns and pretends to be painful, pretending to be sick, even though he is not sick, 

If this is the case, should we use "His face was twisted with pain" to express this situation? Or should not we use "His face was twisted with pain" to express this situation?

Comment: @user22046  That seems like a meaningless distinction.  There's no way to know from "fact twisted with pain" whether the person really is in pain or just faking.  You have to find out that information from the context.  For example, you can say a footballer *"rolled on the ground in **agony**"* after apparently being struck by another player, but how could any of us know if he's really in pain or just faking it?

Comment: @user22046  if you want to be clear that it's a possible sham, then say *"his face was twisted with **apparent** pain"* or something similar.  Then we know it just *looks like* he's in pain, but possibly is not actually in pain.

Comment: I have known that a sentence of "A becuse of B"  is presented a result(A), because we know the fact of B (the cause(B) of the result(A)).

For example, 
Everyone did not know that he was suffering, but he frowns. Is it possible to express this situation as "His face was twisted because of pain" even in such cases? Or is it possible to express this situation as 
""His face was twisted with pain" ?

his face was twisted before we guessed that he was in pain.

Comment: If so, If it is possible for us to express the situation as "His face was twisted with pain", is not it better for foreigners to interpret "with pain" as "appearing pain" instead of interpreting "with pain" as "because of pain"?

I would appreciate if you point out something I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @user22046  It's not clear what you are trying to ask.  There are few if any *completely* unambiguous statements in any language.  Any sentence can mean something different depending on context, body language, intonation, etc.  Without any additional information, we can just assume the most obvious or common meaning.